# Android USB Audio

Tags: android, usb, audio-streaming

Can an Android device in USB Host mode stream audio to a connected USB device?

Android accessory mode doesn't work for me as the USB device that I am connecting to my Android device cannot power the USB bus.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but I found this guide [Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html). Hope it is useful…

Comment: @LaiVung, The Android Accessory Development Kit is not useful here.

Comment: See also:  http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3611/1509  I've heard that the Galaxy S3 supports USB audio out of the box, but it is rare to find a device that does.